# need to send messages through soap requests

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, soap

i have a XML request and i don't have any idea about how to send message through that soap request. my XML request file structure looks like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://schemas.test.com/xsd/kannel/handler/v1/" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soapenv:Header>
<testsms:authData xmlns:testsms="http://testsms.com/">
<testsms:user>username</testsms:user>
<testsms:key>password</testsms:key>
</testsms:authData>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<v1:SMSRequest>
<v1:requestData>
<v1:outSms>message content</v1:outSms>
<v1:recepient>81720233436</v1:recepient>
<v1:depCode>dept code</v1:depCode>
<v1:smscId/>
<v1:billable/>
</v1:requestData>
</v1:SMSRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i need to send message through this soap request. can anyone help me? it is ok with using PHP(Laravel) or NodeJS. i have a request URL.

Comment: Try setting the content-type header as text/xml and sending this XML as string in the body.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez i need to use this request in PHP or NodeJS like we use rest apis.

Comment: Yep, just send the xml instead of a json and change the content-type header. This is just an HTTP request like REST ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you read a bit more on Soap Protocol [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/what_is_soap.htm) so that you have a basic idea of the syntax and tags to follow.

With that move on to use PHP SoapClient in Laravel or alternatively use npm package [Soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) in NodeJS, It totally depends on you to choose the framework according to your familiarity.